# Vagrant error - undefined method `gsub!' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: centos, vagrant

I've been trying to install and run a vagrant instance that brings up a CentOS 7 VM. Ideally i would then be able to use ansible to provision the VM with software.

Unfortunately i keep getting this error whenever i try to bring vagrant up:

```
Installing additional modules ...
vboxadd.sh: Starting the VirtualBox Guest Additions.

Could not find the X.Org or XFree86 Window System, skipping.
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start vboxadd.service
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start vboxadd-service.service
Unmounting Virtualbox Guest Additions ISO from: /mnt
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...
==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:115:in `cygwin_path': undefined method `gsub!' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/plugins/synced_folders/rsync/helper.rb:54:in `rsync_single'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/plugins/synced_folders/rsync/synced_folder.rb:48:in `block in enable'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/plugins/synced_folders/rsync/synced_folder.rb:47:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/plugins/synced_folders/rsync/synced_folder.rb:47:in `enable'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folders.rb:93:in `block in call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folders.rb:90:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folders.rb:90:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folder_cleanup.rb:28:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/plugins/synced_folders/nfs/action_cleanup.rb:19:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_nfs_valid_ids.rb:12:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:49:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_forwarded_port_collision_params.rb:30:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/env_set.rb:19:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:80:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:50:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_check_outdated.rb:78:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/match_mac_address.rb:19:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/discard_state.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:74:in `import'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:13:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_clone_snapshot.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/prepare_clone.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/customize.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:56:in `call'        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:227:in `action_raw'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:202:in `block in action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:631:in `lock'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:188:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:188:in `action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.0/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'

C:\Users\tdias\Desktop\Vagrant>
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling it, but it hasn't worked. I checked the file mentioned and found this:

```
 # This takes any path and converts it from a Windows path to a
    # Cygwin or msys style path.
    #
    # @param [String] path
    # @return [String]
    def cygwin_path(path)
      begin
        # We have to revert to the old env
        # path here, otherwise it looks like
        # msys2 ends up using the wrong cygpath
        # binary and ends up with a `/cygdrive`
        # when it doesn't exist in msys2
        original_path_env = ENV['PATH']
        ENV['PATH'] = ENV['VAGRANT_OLD_ENV_PATH']
        cygpath = Vagrant::Util::Which.which("cygpath")
        cygpath.gsub!("/", '\\')
        process = Subprocess.execute(
          cygpath, "-u", "-a", path.to_s)
        return process.stdout.chomp
      rescue Errors::CommandUnavailableWindows => e
        # Sometimes cygpath isn't available (msys). Instead, do what we
        # can with bash tricks.
        process = Subprocess.execute(
          "bash",
          "--noprofile",
          "--norc",
          "-c", "cd #{Shellwords.escape(path)} && pwd")
        return process.stdout.chomp
      ensure
        ENV['PATH'] = original_path_env
      end
    end
```

Does anyone know how to fix?

Comment: It looks like this script wasn't able to find cygwin.  Do you have cygwin installed?  If so, are you running vagrant within a bash shell?  This issue might be related: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/6788

Comment: I didn't have cygwin installed since this was a fresh windows installation. Installing it and trying again ended with the same result

Comment: can you provide your vagrant file ? and does it happen on nay vagrant command ? run `vagrant status` just to see if you have error or report the command where you have error

Comment: [Here is the vagrant file](https://pastebin.com/WQJKLbE1)    And the result of vagrant update:                           
Current machine states:

default                   not created (virtualbox)

The environment has not yet been created. Run `vagrant up` to
create the environment. If a machine is not created, only the
default provider will be shown. So if a provider is not listed,
then the machine is not created for that environment.

Answer (score 0):

This line is your problem:

```
cygpath.gsub!("/", '\\')
```

You are trying to change all "/" in your string with '\', but there is no "/" in your text, if you use `gsub` insted of `gsub!`, you will not get this error.

Comment: I'm afraid i'm a bit of a noob at using vagrant. How would i do that?

Comment: This is part of the `vagrant` library not the OP code base. @TiagoDias do not change this your issue is configuration driven not code driven.